# C# CONTACT FORM

Tags: c#, .net, gmail

I'm trying to build a contact form in my Site, where customers can send email for me(ADM).
So I'm using stmp client to do that, but when I send a email from the contact form, it appears like I send it to myself.
Here is the code.

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(command.Email); //sender email address 
        mailMessage.From = fromAddress;
        mailMessage.To.Add("myEmail@gmail.com");    //receiver email address               
        mailMessage.Body = command.Message;
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mailMessage.Subject = "Contact Us";

        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtpClient.Port = 587;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myEmail@gmail.com", "password");
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

How can I set the right email, so I can receive from the customers and not myself haha.?

[image: To me Image]

Comment: You may well not be able to send the email from another recipient. While technically you can set the FROM or REPLY-TO headers to any value you want, your SMTP provider (Gmail) might see that as an attempt to be deceptive and might change the FROM header you have set. That's just speculation, but it would explain what you see.

Comment: I see...So, how can I know who is sendind me a email?

Comment: Put the sender's email address in the body or subject

Comment: RIGHTT! Didn't thought about that!! Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

The Google smtp server automatically changes the From field to match the credentials used to log in. If an smtp server allows anybody to send mail from any address, it probably won't be trusted by other mail servers, and the messages will be ignored or marked as spam.

Comment: Hmmmm, Sooo, how can I know who is sending the email? oO

Answer (score 0):

Additional to the answer of @tsandy there is something you need to change as I see. So I guess the command.Email is the customer's email address. Your code might look like following.

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("myEmail@gmail.com"); //sender email address 
mailMessage.From = fromAddress;
mailMessage.To.Add("myEmail@gmail.com");    //receiver email address               
mailMessage.Body = command.Message;
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
mailMessage.DisplayName = command.email; //This line is added
mailMessage.Subject = "Contact Us";

SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtpClient.Port = 587;
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myEmail@gmail.com", "password");
smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

In this case you will be like sending yourself an email but in the mail signature you will at least see the customer's email